# What is the point of 'L' here?

Tags: c++

```
//Using the if-else
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  long number = 0;                  // Store input here
  cout << "Enter an integer less than 2 billion: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << endl;

  if(number % 2L == 0)              // Test remainder after division by 2
    cout << "Your number is even."  // Here if remainder is 0
         << endl;
  else
    cout << "Your number is odd."   // Here if remainder is 1
         << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here, in the first 'if' condition, why do they have 'L' after 2? taking 'L' out seems to run the code just fine.

Comment: There is no need for it here.

Comment: What does L do though? If I ever needed it?

Comment: It only pertains to `long` literals.

Comment: Take the `L` out and try entering a really, really big number.  Then you'll be dividing a `long` by an `int`.  May or may not cause a problem.

Comment: 2L is a long literal. 2 on its own is an int literal. Because number is a long, the 2 would have been promoted to a long as well, so the code is equivalent with and without the L.

Comment: @nhgrif No. Integer literals are not necessarily `int`, they're at least `int`s (and `long int`s if `int` is not sufficient).

Answer (score 11):

The `L` suffix is used to signify that a number literal is of type `long int`. Normally it is not necessary if you are just assigning the value to a variable, since, as for C++11 §2.14.2 ¶2 (and in particular table 6), a decimal integer literal without suffix will be of the first type that can represent it between `int`, `long int` or `long long int`.<sup>1</sup>

So, you *don't* risk to have the value itself truncated; but:

1. you do have a certain degree of uncertainty about the type of the literal (`32768` may be an `int` or a `long`, depending from the platform/compiler);
2. you may inadvertently get a literal of the wrong type for your specific expression.

So, you need to specify `L` instead in contexts where you want to be sure that the type of the literal is `long` (or bigger); two important cases come to mind:

- resolving overloads; if you have two overloads of a function, one for `int` and one for `long`, and you want to be sure to call the `long` one even if you are passing a small number, you'll have to use a `long` literal;

  ```
  void foo(int);
  void foo(long);

  foo(1);      // <-- will call the first overload
  foo(1L);     // <-- will call the second overload
  foo(32768);  // <-- may call the first or the second overload, depending
               //     from the specific platform
  foo(32768L); // <-- will call the second overload
  ```
- but most importantly: avoid surprises when doing arithmetic; if you perform e.g. a multiplication like this:

  ```
  int a;
  ...
  long v=32767*a; // don't let the "long" fool you - 32767*a is evaluated as an int!
  ```

  `32767` is an `int` literal (since it's small enough to fit an `int`), `a` is an `int`, and the result will be an `int`, even if you are assigning to a `long`. This may be a problem if `a` can be big enough to overflow your calculation; by specifying a `long` literal, you guarantee that you'll perform a `long` multiplication.

  ```
  long v=32767L*a; // now we are doing all the math with longs
  ```

  (This problem is actually *way* more frequent with division and FP literals, where often you have to specify `double` or `float` literals to get the intended "real division" behavior)

  As *@chris* suggests, a way more frequent situation (of this same kind) arises when doing "big" bitshifts, e.g.:

  ```
  long long mask=1<<53;
  ```

  presents the same problem as above: `1` is an `int`, `53` is an `int`, the computation will be performed with `int`s, resulting in overflow (although in this particular case any decent compiler will issue a warning); here the correct form would be:

  ```
  long long mask=1LL<<53; // LL is the suffix for long long
  ```

---

Coming to your particular code: there's no risk in taking the `L` away; since `number` is already a `long`, `2` will be promoted to `long` anyway in doing the modulo (as per the "usual arithmetic conversions", §5 ¶10, and §4.5), so here `L` makes no difference.

Still, in many cases it's not a bad idea to keep the literal of the "intended type": it guarantees that, even if the type of the other operand is changed for some reason to a narrower type, the computation will still be done in the intended way (not that for modulo it would make any difference).

---

1. > The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be
   >   represented.
   >   [image: table from the C++11 standard describing the type to be used for integer literals]

Comment: I find this commonly happens with something like `1 << 53`.

Comment: @chris: yes, that bit me too several times; I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: At least compilers (GCC) do a good job of warning about that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no need for it.

The `L` indicates a long value which means it reserves more space just your calculation will go beyond the range of a normal integer.

Comment: `L` is not related to variables, but to literals. If you are assigning the result to a variable, it will be sized according to its type, what you assign to it won't make any difference (unless we are talking about the initialization of `auto` variables).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: assigned or not assigned, it is still a variable in your memory and used for calculation as such. Not doing this can screw up your calculation _before_ storing it in your assignment

Comment: Nope, a literal is *not* a variable, it's a primary expression, and in most expressions it will just stay in a register or as an immediate value in the generated assembly. The fact that using the wrong type of literal can mess your calculation, of course, is true, though it's not related to "reserved space in memory", but to how the type information tells to the compiler how to perform the calculation.

Comment: Are you refuting that an int has a different memory footprint from a long long int? If not than I don't see how it is not related to the "reserved space in memory", it is not the only difference but it is definitely relevant.

Comment: No, I'm saying that in the context of a simple expression (like the one in the original post) it's mostly irrelevant, since the literal is almost surely embedded as an immediate value in the generated assembly. Also, such simple calculations will probably be done in the CPU registers, *maybe* hitting the memory only when storing it in a variable, and, in that case, the storage space used depends from the type of the target variable, not that of the expression. Again: getting the literals type is necessary to let the compiler generate the correct code, the used space (if any) is a side effect.

Comment: And if you exceed 32 bits on a 32 bit cpu (or in 32 bit mode) it will overflow the register. So yes, it's still quite relevant regardless of whether it hits the memory.